# How to align HighCharts (bar chart) bars to the top/front?

Tags: charts, highcharts, alignment, bar-chart

I am facing this issue with HighCharts - Bar charts.

When my dataset does not have enough data (say there are only two bars across a chart area designed to display 20 bars), the bars stretch themselves superthick.
Like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/32toL65L/

So, to push the bars to the top, I added

```
plotOptions-> car-> maxPointSidth:15; //Fix max bar width to 15 pixels
x-axis -> max : 20;  // Move bars to top two positions
series[0].data. push(['',0])  x 18 times // to display 18 empty blocks
```

It almost worked.. Almost! 
But numbers are being displayed from 3 to 20 in xAxis label, which I can't figure out how to remove..
Here is the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aux4vgmq/

What am I doing wrong? Why do those numbers show up when my dataset is filled with empty characters for x-axis label?

Could you please provide any suggestions on how to remove those extra numbers or how to configure HighCharts to align bars to the top?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Specify the category names in the xAxis definition and not in the data.

```
xAxis: {
    max: 10,
    type: 'category',        
    categories: ['Shanghai', 'Lagos','','','','','','','','','']
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e3hw4pv4/

Comment: Numbers show up for categories because there are no categories defined but data has more, so {point.name} is taken instead. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.data.name

Answer (score 0):

You can set xAxis using [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setCategories). Dynamic way to generate the set categories for xAxis from series provides.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        events: {
                 load: function (e) {
                 var series_data=this.series[0].data
                 var categoriesArr=[];
                 for(var i=0;i<series_data.length;i++){
                            categoriesArr.push(series_data[i].name)
                 }
                  this.xAxis[0].setCategories(categoriesArr);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
            max:10,
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: 0,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
    },
    plotOptions:{
          bar :{
            maxPointWidth:15
          }
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
            ['Shanghai', 23.7],
            ['Lagos', 16.1],
            ['',0],
            ['',0],
            ['',0],

            ['',0],
            ['',0],
            ['',0],
            ['',0],
            ['',0],
            ['',0],

        ]
    }]
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/p4oqu8yw/)

Comment: An body having solution better than this .I have also face similar issue of having wide bars/columns when  series  length is less

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution Gayan Dasanayake & Deep 3015.

I found a messy way to fix this issue by using blankspace strings of different length for xAxis Labels.  I stumbled across this fix by trial and error and I am not entirely sure why it works.

```
  data: [
        ['Shanghai', 23.7],
        ['Lagos', 16.1],
        ['',0],
        [' ',0],
        ['  ',0],

        ['   ',0],
        ['    ',0],
        ['     ',0],
        ['      ',0],
        ['       ',0],
        ['        ',0]

    ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4voq0hb9/2/

I prefer your solution as setting xAxis categories dynamically is definitely a cleaner way than generating strings with blankspaces.